# Auto-generating migration based on entity definition - Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

Hello to all **Shopware** devs.

I am new in **Shopware** development and I was surprise to see that while **Symfony** has a "doctrine generate migration" command that auto generate **SQL** migrations, **Shopware** does not seem to have this and following the tutorials, it seems that I have to write both the entity definition and the migration **SQL** to create the corresponding table.

This is painful to do for tables with many fields.
Is there any solution to auto-generate it, making sure there is no mistake? Maybe a plugin?

Finally and if not, is it somehow planned on the roadmap?

Thank you all in advance to help me answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer the question for everyone else who comes across this.

Shopware supports now the cli command `bin/console dal:create:schema` which is generating the Schema from the Entites.

**Keep in mind:** *At the current time in March 2020, this function is still in beta. So double check the generated schema file.*

[SQL Schema Documentation](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/plugin-migrations#sql-schema)

> This command selects all active entity definitions known to Shopware and tries to create SQL queries on base of the fields. Note: Your plugin has to be activated, otherwise your custom entity definition will not be considered. The queries are outputted into /schema. Search for the correct SQL file and copy the query to your migration file. Note: This command is in beta state and should not be used blindly Double check if the generated SQL query really fits your needs.